# Python iterate over multiple elements

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have a nested list of integers:

```
dimensions = [[3, 12, 42], [19, 16, 10], ..., [2, 13, 20]]
```

I need to flatten the list by performing this operation on every sublist:

```
[a, b, c] ==> 2 * (ab + bc + ac)
```

I managed to do it in a very explicit way, I was wondering if there was a more elegant/pythonic solution

Comment: It might be a good idea to show what your original solution was, for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you don't need anything more complicated than

```
[2 * (a*b + b*c + a*c) for a,b,c in dimensions]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to produce the pairings of the items:

```
from itertools import combinations
[sum(a * b for a, b in combinations(l, 2)) * 2 for l in dimensions]
```

so that given:

```
dimensions = [[3, 12, 42], [19, 16, 10], [2, 13, 20]]
```

this returns:

```
[1332, 1308, 652]
```

Answer (score 0):

As a one-liner in a list comprehension.

```
[2* (e[0]*e[1] + e[1]*e[2] + e[0]*e[2]) for e in dimensions]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
result = []
for sublist in dimensions:
        for a,b c in sublist:
             value = 2*(a*b+b*c+a*c)
             result.append(value)
print(result)
```